# Rails - NoMethodError even though method is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So my goal with this method is to have it link to customers/1/showcar similar to how it will link to customers/1/edit, which is how I'm attempting to model my code.

My controller is

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :showcar]

  # GET /customers
  # GET /customers.json
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
  end

  # GET /customers/1
  # GET /customers/1.json
  def show
  end
  # GET /customers/1/showcar
  def showcar
  end

  # GET /customers/new
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
  end

  # GET /customers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /customers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /customers/1
  # DELETE /customers/1.json
  def destroy
    @customer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customers_url, notice: 'Customer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_customer
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:cust_id, :cust_fname, :cust_lname, :cust_phone, :cust_addr, :cust_date)
    end
end
```

and my html.erb file where I'm attempting to call the method is

```
<style>
th, td{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Customers</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cust ID</th>
      <th>Cust fname</th>
      <th>Cust lname</th>
      <th>Cust phone</th>
      <th>Cust addr</th>
      <th>Cust date</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <% belongstocust = Car.where(cust_id: customer.cust_id) %>
      <tr> 
        <td><%= customer.cust_id %></td>
        <td><%= customer.cust_fname %></td>
        <td><%= customer.cust_lname %></td>
        <td><%= customer.cust_phone %></td>
        <td><%= customer.cust_addr %></td>
        <td><%= customer.cust_date %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', customer %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        #placeholder, not permanent code
        <% i = '' %>
        <% belongstocust.each do |car| %>
          <% i = car.car_model %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show ' + i, car_path(car) %></td>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show Car', showcar_customer_path(customer) %> </td> 
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Customer', new_customer_path %>
<br>
<%= link_to 'Home', home_index_path %>
```

The issue is, whenever I have the code `<td><%= link_to 'Show Car', showcar_customer_path(customer) %> </td>`, I get the noMethodError even though the method is defined inside the controller, and it looks the exact same as def show and def edit. I've tried making a controller called customer, and adding the showcar method to that controller, and it worked, but it wouldn't pass over the customer. I also tried adding showcar to customer.rb, but it also gave me a noMethodError. I'm a complete noob when it comes to ruby, and was just told to make a project using the framework, so I've been having to learn along the way. This could be a really simple issue that I don't know how to solve due to my ignorance, so if that's the case I'm sorry.

Comment: Learning while doing is, of course, a way to go. But it will be very helpful to set aside a week and complete [the rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) or one of the online courses. You'll get a complete overview of the framework and will be able to navigate and solve problems quicker.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you posted this. I'll be sure to read over this! I really had no clue where/what to start learning, so i've just been looking up what I've needed at a given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get the noMethodError even though the method is defined inside the controller

No. You have `showcar` defined, not `showcar_customer_path`. You are missing a route, the thing that defines `xxx_path` methods.

In your `config/routes.rb` you probably have

```
resources :customers
```

To register this new action, you can do

```
resources :customers do
  member do
    get :showcar
  end
end
```

Now `showcar_customer_path` should be available to use in the views.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no clue that it needed to be routed since show and edit weren't routed. Unless ' resources :customers' is what gives them their routing.

Comment: @Varri: yep, that's exactly what `resources :customers` does. define routes for seven standard actions.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how come resources :customers doesn't include showcar? Is it built into ruby that resources :customers only includes the basic CRUD generated by scaffolding? I think that's where I got hung up, because I thought resources :customers routed EVERYTHING in the customers controller.

Comment: @Varri: no, not everything, The key word: "seven standard actions". Which are: index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thank you again Sergio, you've helped a lot.